# Non degenerate bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

**Problem:**

> Let $F:V \times W \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non degenerate bilinear form. The question is: prove that $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension (the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional)

My answer is: $F$ is non degenerate, then the matrix of $F$ is invertible, which means it's square and this implies that $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension. Is my assumption that the matrix of a non degenerate bilinear form is invertible true? Also let me know if my answer is true?

Comment: Hint: What is the definition of non-degeneracy?  If $V$ and $W$ have different dimension, can $F$ be non-degenerate?  PS- $F$ does not have a matrix if you have not chosen bases of the vector spaces.

Comment: @Dylan Moreland : Yes, I assume $V$ and $W$ to be finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @Dylan Moreland  I have already added that to the problem statement. So, now in finite dimensional case, what do you think about the assumption of invertibility?

Comment: @Zi2018Alpha Great! What's your definition of non-degenerate?

Comment: Is the particular definition going to matter too much?  Aren't they all more or less "only zero kills everything"?

Comment: @Neal Not so much in the finite-dimensional case. Some people take it as the definition that there are induced isomorphisms $V \to W^*$, $W \to V^*$. But proving that these are equivalent in this case is not so bad. I'll probably write an answer.

Comment: @Dylan Okay, I see your concern about finite-dimensionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can obtain a linear map $V \to W^*$ by sending $x \in V$ to the functional $y \mapsto F(x, y)$ on $W$. That $F$ is non-degenerate implies that this map is injective, so $\dim V \leq \dim W^*$. Since $W$ is finite-dimensional, $W^*$ has the same dimension as $W$ and hence $\dim V \leq \dim W$. Using the analogous map $W \to V^*$, we get the reverse inequality.

Comment: You could make a very similar argument using the fact that the row and column rank of a matrix for $F$ are the same. Might write that up later.

Comment: Slick!  I was thinking of showing that some subspace of higher-dimensional space annihilated everything in the lower-dimensional space and deriving a contradiction, but this amounts to the same thing and is much better.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to show that the matrix is invertible - in fact you just have reformulated your problem. Sometimes such a reformulation can be helpful, but it is by no means a solution.